# How can I convert these streamed Map keys from Longs to Objects?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I've current got a method which looks like:

```
public Map<Long, List<ReferralDetailsDTO>> getWaiting() {
        return referralDao.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(ReferralDetailsDTO::new)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ReferralDetailsDTO::getLocationId, Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

It returns me a Map of location IDs to ReferralDetailsDTO objects. However, I'd like to swap out the location ID for the LocationDTO object.

I'd have naively imagined something like this might work:

```
public Map<Long, List<ReferralDetailsDTO>> getWaiting() {
    return referralDao.findAll()
            .stream()
            .map(ReferralDetailsDTO::new)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(locationDao.findById(ReferralDetailsDTO::getLocationId), Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Obviously, I'm here because it doesn't - Java complains the findById method is expecting a Long value, not the method reference. Any suggestions for how I can neatly address this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no need to call `groupingBy(... , toList())`. The one-parameter of the `groupingBy` method (the one where you provide a key-mapping for the data in the pipeline) already put the values for a same key in a `List`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, change the key type of the Map from Long to your relevant class (is it `LocationDTO` or some other class?)

Second of all, use a lambda expression instead of method reference for the lookup :

```
public Map<LocationDTO, List<ReferralDetailsDTO>> getWaiting() {
    return referralDao.findAll()
            .stream()
            .map(ReferralDetailsDTO::new)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> locationDao.findById(r.getLocationId()));
}
```